# show hide div javascript passing values from a form to another

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to collect some values on the form inside (**`mydiv`**), pass those values to a form bellow **(`mydiv2`)**, hide **(`mydiv`)** and show **(`mydiv2`)** after user submission.

The problem is that I'm using the `onload event` to populate the input field "displayName" of the form inside **(`mydiv2`)** and this makes it impossible to use other method to swap divs...

Is this possible? Is there any other way to do this?

**This is my code so far:**

```
<div id="mydiv">
<!-- div to show by default and hide after users submit the form below -->
<form id="loginForm" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="j_name" value="" placeholder="name here"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
<!-- div to hide by default and show after users submit the form above -->
<form id="2Form">
 <input type="text" name="displayName" value="" placeholder="name here"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<?php $the_name = $_POST['j_name'];?>

<script>
// Wait for the DOM to finish loading.
var previousOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function () {

    // Execute any other `onload` function which may have been bound previously.
    if (typeof previousOnload === 'function') {
        previousOnload();
    }

document.getElementsByName('displayName')[0].value = "<?php echo $the_name; ?>";

};
</script>
```

Comment: Could you simply use `#mydiv2 {visibility:hidden}`? This would allow you to populate the displayName of #mydiv2 because it keeps it in the DOM - but #mydiv2 will not be visible.

Comment: @LennieCodes No. The other form (on `#mydiv2`) has other fields that must be populated by the user. I need to hide `#mydiv2` by default and show it only after user submits the **loginform** hiding `#mydiv` at the same time.

Comment: What if you use a "onchange" event in the input to populate the form in the div2?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña nop

Comment: You will have to use an AJAX function to save the form, instead of submit, make a JS function to save the data, without the need of reloading the page, once its finished, show the div2 populated with the data.